# Fade out and reload using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is to fadeout div and then reload page, after page reload fadeIn div and stop reloading page. The problem here after fadeOut dive reloading does not stop so fadeOut does not work ?

Code:`update`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut('slow', function () {
        location.reload(true); 
        $("#myDiv").fadeIn(4500);
    });
});
```

Comment: When the page reloads, how will this script be entered again?

Comment: Are you talking about fading with AJAX?

Comment: Fading with JQuery, I am doing this for reloading page in order to refresh some content

Comment: I'm confused by your code. Why are you setting `window.location.href` to itself?

Comment: it might be wrong but I am trying to use for reloading page

Comment: What is purpose of reloading page ?

Comment: some contents need to reload page in order to append the right data

Comment: `js` at Question reloading page recursively ?

Answer (score 1):

> the problem here if i add hash to end of url it will not work properly
>   because url has id = number like this
>   localhost:49208/CMMS/UserView.aspx?id=8

Try setting `localStorage` first `.fadeOut()` call , if `localStorage` has unique item set fade out `#myDiv` using `$.holdReady()`, then fade in `#myDiv` . See also [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/)

```
$.holdReady(true);
  if (localStorage.getItem("reload") === "#") {
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut();
  }
$.holdReady(false);
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("reload") === null) {
      $("#myDiv").fadeOut('slow', function () {
        localStorage.setItem("reload", "#");          
        window.location.href = window.location.href            
      });
    } else {
        $("#myDiv").fadeIn(4500);
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem here if i add hash to end of url it will not work properly because url has `id = number` like this `localhost:49208/CMMS/UserView.aspx?id=8`

Comment: Try substituting  `history` or `localStorage` for query string or hash ; using same process including `$.holdReady()` to check for variables in `window` before `.ready()` handler called ; see link at updated post

Comment: @Smart See updated post ; substituted `localStorage` for setting unique query string or hash at `location.href`